# MS-Excel automatic increase number if text not same

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, vba

[image: Fig1]

As shown above picture i need put number on column **B** that automatic increase if text on column **A** not same so the the result would be

[image: Fig2]

Can I do that with ms-excel?

Answer (score 1):

Put `1` on `B1` and put below on `B2` and drag down

```
=if(a2=a1, b1, b1+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using vba, assuming your working on the 1st sheet, you can use code like this:

```
Sub uniqueIdx()

  Dim idx As Integer: idx = 1
  Dim c As Range

  With Sheets(1)
    For Each c In .Range("A1", .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)):
      .Cells(c.row, 2).Value = idx
      If (c.Value <> c.Offset(1, 0).Value) Then idx = idx + 1
    Next
  End With

End Sub
```